# Pyramid apex/ pyramid_rpc conflict

Tags: python, pyramid, pylons, json-rpc

I've run into an issue trying to combine Apex and pyramid_rpc in a pyramid app.
I'm running: pyramid 1.4, pyramid_rpc 0.5.1, apex 0.9.10dev on python 2.7.3

All my jsonrpc requests were returning 32600 errors. To enable pyramid_rpc in my _init I have:

```
config.include('pyramid_rpc.jsonrpc')
```

I knew my rpc calls and services were good so I searched high and low, simplifying everything. The culprit turned out to be a single line:

```
config.include("apex")
```

Without apex enabled my rpc calls run fine.

Saintly Pyramid Gurus, any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: Can you post any more info on what's going on? Like what routes you may have registered via proutes? I'm the author of both velruse and pyramid_rpc but I am not entirely excited about stabbing in the dark for issues. :-)

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that apex requires csrf tokens on every post request. You need to exclude your JSON-RPC endpoints from this requirement by setting the `apex.no_csrf` ini setting appropriately. In my dummy application I have `config.add_jsonrpc_endpoint('foo', '/foo/jsonrpc')`. It was returning -32600 until I set `apex.no_csrf = apex:callback,foo`. Note that there is no space between the comma-delimited options.

Comment: I'm not sure I ever would have tracked that one down. Thanks for you help (also for velruse and _rpc)!